# jQuery Countdown - Change 0 Days Into Today

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-countdown

I'm working on countdown page using Keith Woods Countdown jquery plugin http://keith-wood.name/countdown.html. And this is what I have so far

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var segera = new Date();
segera = new Date(segera.getFullYear(), 2 - 1, 28);
$('.days').countdown({
    until: segera,
    layout: '{dn} {dl}',
    timezone: +7
});
$('.hours').countdown({
    until: segera,
    layout: '{hn} {hl} {mn} {ml}',
    timezone: +7
});
});
```

The question is, how can I change the day format? So, instead of displaying 0 DAYS, it will display TODAY.
Any help would really be appreciated...

//// EDIT

A facebook friend helped me. And here's what worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var segera = new Date();
segera = new Date(segera.getFullYear(), 2 - 1, 28);
$('.days').countdown({
    until: segera,
    layout: '{dn} {dl}',
    timezone: +7,
    expiryText: "TODAY"
});
$('.hours').countdown({
    until: segera,
    layout: '{hn} {hl} {mn} {ml}',
    timezone: +7
});
var hari = $('.days').text();
if (hari == "0 Days") {
    $('.days').css('display', 'none');
    $('.result').text('Today');
}
});
```

See [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajibari/9AVFV/6/)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `expiryText` property to any string you want:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var segera = new Date();
    segera = new Date(segera.getFullYear(), 2 - 1, 28);
    $('.days').countdown({
        until: segera,
        layout: '{dn} {dl}',
        timezone: +7,
        expiryText: "TODAY"
    });
    $('.hours').countdown({
        until: segera,
        layout: '{hn} {hl} {mn} {ml}',
        timezone: +7,
        expiryText: "TODAY"
    });
});
```

[Source](http://keith-wood.name/countdownRef.html) (look for "expiryText")

Comment: Thanks for the help @Quinn, and for the source too. But unfortunately it doesn't work, as you can see in this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/leoaw/9AVFV/4/). I wonder what was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set "alwaysExpire: true" in the parameters